# SQL Sum Columns

Tags: sql

I want to get the following output:

Main table:

```
Email       | Group | id
a@gmail.com | Y     | 1
a@gmail.com | Y     | 2 
b@gmail.com | N     | 3
c@gmail.com | N     | 4
```

Join Table:

```
Email       | Value
a@gmail.com | 10
b@gmail.com | 20
c@gmail.com | 30
```

Desired result (only take the a@gmail.com value once, despite appearing in the first table twice):

```
Group  | Email Count | Sum
Y      | 1           | 10
N      | 2           | 50
```

Here is the sqlfiddle I've been playing around with:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a24d/8

Comment: what happen if `a@gmail.com` appear as `Y` and `N` ?? is possible?

Comment: that's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in your SQLFiddle. You just needed to join on a distinct select.

```
SELECT  
e.Unsub as Unsub,
count(e.email) as EmailCount,
sum(c.sum) as EmailSum
FROM CountTable c
JOIN (select distinct email, Unsub from EmailsTable) e on c.email = e.email
GROUP BY e.unsub
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a24d/16/0)

Comment: 1) Dont need `LEFT JOIN`, normal `JOIN` will do 2) dont need `COUNT(DISTINCT`, already did the `DISTINCT` on the `subquery`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I fixed his query to work, but I did not optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

First remove the duplicates, and then do the calculations

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2a24d/15)**

```
SELECT filter.`Unsub`, COUNT(*),  SUM(`sum`)
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT `Unsub`, `email` 
        FROM EmailsTable ) as filter
JOIN  CountTable    
  ON filter.`email` = CountTable.`email` 
GROUP BY  filter.`Unsub`
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Unsub | COUNT(*) | SUM(`sum`) |
|-------|----------|------------|
|     N |        2 |         50 |
|     Y |        1 |         10 |
```